# how to add a name with apostrophe s into the Google ecommerce tracking code?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

I am using Google e-commerce tracking code for tracking registrations but few company names having apostrophe s in their name are not getting reported by the code.

Please have a look at the link and then at the code below:
[Google ecommerce tracking] https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingEcommerce#Example

```
 var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
   '1234',           // order ID - required
   'L'Oreal',        // affiliation or store name
   '11.99',          // total - required
   '1.29',           // tax
   '5',              // shipping
   'San Jose',       // city
   'California',     // state or province
   'USA'             // country
 ]);
```

I guess L'Oreal contains a `'` in its name and `affiliation or store name` above will consider only `L` as its name and it will get Oreal as extra and it stops submitting the data to Google.

For this, can we use double quotes as below:

```
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-xxxxx-x");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
pageTracker._addTrans(
  "1234",            // order ID - required
  "L'oreal",  // affiliation or store name
  "11.99",           // total - required
  "1.29",            // tax
  "15.00",           // shipping
  "San Jose",        // city
  "California",      // state or province
  "USA"              // country
);
```

OR any bypassing is required? 
Please suggest...

Answer (score 1):

You can use double quotes, but I'd suggest using single quotes and escaping any single quotes in the text by putting a `\` before them:

```
_gaq.push(['_addTrans',
  '1234',           // order ID - required
  'L\'Oreal',        // affiliation or store name
...
```